# WCM and WCS session management

Tags: websphere, wcs, wcm

We have the set up in such a way that WCM has containers where the angular code will reside and call our WCS services for getting the details required to paint the UI page.

We have the session management set at wc-server.xml as 30 minutes. Once the session expires, WCS services are returning "Activity token as expired".

Can we handle the session management in an effective way in WCM layer itself than at WCS service side?

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

Send a keep alive ping every 29 minutes? Otherwise it will have to re-establish a new session once it expires.